# How do I install DiscoveryStudio and PyRx in Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation

Please Help me to Install Discovery Studio and PyRx in Ubuntu.
Answer will be expected in detail.
Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

### [Discovery Studio](https://www.3ds.com/products-services/biovia/products/molecular-modeling-simulation/biovia-discovery-studio/)

First, download the installer for Ubuntu. Open a terminal and enter the following commands one by one.

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget https://www.3ds.com/fileadmin/PRODUCTS-SERVICES/BIOVIA/BIOVIA_Visualizer/BIOVIA_2021.DS2021Client.bin
sh BIOVIA_2021.DS2021Client.bin
```

It is a closed source proprietary software. Contact the manufacturer for support.

### [PyRX](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyrx/)

Open a terminal, and move to the downloads folder. Then, download the latest version of pyrx with the following commands.

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget https://telkomuniversity.dl.sourceforge.net/project/pyrx/0.9/pyrx-0.9.2-linux-x86_64.tar.gz
```

Now, extract the gzipped tarball.

```
tar -xzvf pyrx-0.9.2-linux-x86_64.tar.gz
```

Then, change directory and run the installer.

```
cd PyRx
./run.sh
```